# please check my understanding about convergences with an example (probability theory)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider $\Omega = [0,1]$ with $\textbf{P}=U[0,1]$. Let $X\equiv 0$,
$$X_1 := \textbf{1}_{[0,1/2)},X_2 := \textbf{1}_{[1/2,1)},X_3 := \textbf{1}_{[0,1/3)},X_4 := \textbf{1}_{[1/3,2/3)},X_5 := \textbf{1}_{[2/3,1)} $$
$$X_6 := \textbf{1}_{[0,1/4)},X_7 := \textbf{1}_{[1/4,2/4)},X_8 := \textbf{1}_{[2/4,3/4)},X_9 := \textbf{1}_{[3/4,1)}$$

It is not "almost surely" convergent, but is convergent in probability, distribution.

1. I think it is not almost surely convergence as we will see $1$ infinitely often. Thus $\textbf{P}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|X_n-0|>\varepsilon)=1$.
2. This is because as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $X_n$ is defined on very small interval -- measure zero, thus $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\textbf{P}(|X_n-0| >\varepsilon$) =0$.
3. $\textbf{I am really confused with this. because $F_X(0)=1$, but $F_{X_n}(0)=0$}$ Please help me with question 3 especially.

Comment: In (1) it should be $$P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\lvert X_n-0\rvert>\varepsilon)=1$$ because technically $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert X_n-0\rvert>\varepsilon)=0$

Comment: In (2) you are missing the absolute value in "$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\lvert X_n-0\rvert>\varepsilon)=0$" and the meaning the following sentences is obscure to me: a) "as $n\to\infty$, $X_n$ has value" b) "because of measure zero".

Comment: For (3), the fact is that, since $X$ is the constant function $0$, $F_X$ is discontinuous at $0$, so [$F_{X_n}(0)$ doesn't need to converge to $F_X(0)$ as $n\to\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Definition).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli For any $t \in [0,1), F_{X_n}(t) =0, but F_X(t) =1$. It is not only discontinuous at 0..

Comment: No: Let $\left[a_n,a_n+2^{-k_n}\right]$ the interval such that $$X_n=1_{\left[a_n,a_n+2^{-k_n}\right]}$$ Then $$F_{X_n}(t)=P(X_n\le t)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }t< 0 \\ 1-2^{-k_n} & \text{if }0\le t<1\\ 1 & \text{if }t\ge1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: As you can see, $F_{X_n}\to 1_{[0,\infty)}$, which actually coincides with $F_0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I got it! Thanks